# Concise notation for last element of an array

Tags: arrays, f#

Is there a concise notation to access last element of an array, similar to std::vector::back() in C++? Do I have to write:

```
veryLongArrayName.[veryLongArrayName.Length-1]
```

each time?

Comment: You can do `Seq.last veryLongArrayName`, but it won't be anywhere near as efficient. Why not just write an inline function for this once and call _that_ each time?

Comment: @ildjarn Funny thing, I was just re-reading my question and I thought of the same answer. The only downside is creation of subjective language dialect: some people will use "back" the others may like "last" better, etc.

Comment: `Seq.last` already sets the precedent here; `back` is a C++ism, largely due to the standard library's need to distinguish between iterators and values (i.e. `end` vs. `back`).

Comment: @ildjarn I think your suggestion is the right answer. Could you post it as an answer (so that we can upvote it and Paul can accept it :-))?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>Expanding from comment</sub>

The built-in option is `Seq.last veryLongArrayName`, but note that this is O(N) rather than O(1), so for all but the smallest arrays probably too inefficient for practical use.

That said, there's no harm in abstracting this functionality yourself:

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Array =
    let inline last (arr:_[]) = arr.[arr.Length - 1]
```

Now you can do `Array.last veryLongArrayName` with no overhead whatsoever, while keeping the code very idiomatic and readable.

Comment: Great! I will copy and paste it into the bag of useful tricks file. I just started with F# a few days ago, so it will take me another couple of days to find out what these attributes mean.

Comment: @Paul : The attributes aren't strictly necessary, I just added them because the built-in F# `Array` module has them. Essentially the first attribute causes the `Array` module to be named `ArrayModule` in IL (i.e. that's how other languages will see it if it's public), and the second attribute prohibits doing `open Array`.

Answer (score 9):

I can not find it in the official documents, but F# 4 seems to have `Array.last` implemented out of the box:

```
/// Returns the last element of the array.
/// array: The input array.
val inline last : array:'T [] -> 'T
```

[Link to implementation at github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I think it's a useful addition to core F#.

Comment: F# 4 implemented matching functionality for Seq, List and Array. Since Seq.last already existed, Array.last had to be made.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to writing a function for _[], you can also write an extension property for IList<'T>:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

[<AutoOpen>]
module IListExtensions =
    type IList<'T> with 
        member self.Last = self.[self.Count - 1]

let lastValue = [|1; 5; 13|].Last // 13
```